# Force a thread to use same input line when using CSV Data Set Config

Tags: testing, jmeter

I am trying to build a Jmeter test plan that can make http calls to a server. Each thread in the thread group will read 2 parameters from a CSV file and make the http call with the params, and continue to make the same call with same parameters for lets say 1000 times with a delay of 10s between each thread execution.

The http call looks like

```
/service/method?param1=${param1}&param2=${param2}
```

The CSV is like this:

```
1,2
3,4
5,6
7,8
```

I have the test plan set up that works for the most part except the single issue. I want each thread to use the same parameters (same line of input) whenever the thread executes. Currently the only way to do it is to set `Recycle on EOF = true`, but the threads randomly pick the values. Param1 and Param2 can be randomly generated values as long as they stick with the same thread throughout the execution.

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really sure I understand your issue right (you can possibly describe it more explicitly or using an example) but the schema below should implement your test-plan description:

```
Test Plan
    Thread Group
    Number of Threads: N
        . . .
        While Controller
        Condition: ${__javaScript("${param2"!="<EOF>",)} - read csv-file until the EOF 
            CSV Data Set Config
            Filename: [path to your file with test-data]
            Variable Names: param1,param2
            Recycle on EOF? False
            Stop thread on EOF? True
            Sharing mode: Current thread group
            Loop Controller
            Loop Count = 1000 - number of loops for each thread, with the same params
                HTTP Request - your http call
                Test Action
                Target = Current Thread
                Action = Pause
                Duration (ms) = 10000 - pause between calls
            . . .
```

In case if you need that each of N threads reads and uses **single and unique** line from csv-file you have to set `Sharing mode: Current thread group` for CSV Data Set Config (number of csv-entries should be in this case the sane as threads number, or `Recycle on EOF? False` should be set otherwise).
In case if you need that each of N threads reads and uses **all** lines from csv-file you have to set `Sharing mode: Current thread` for CSV Data Set Config.

If that's not what you want please describe your issue a bit more clear.

Comment: See my answer for a hack. I did try to do something similar to what you have described (before posting this question), but I found that if you set Recycle on EOF? False, then the test stops after 1 run. If Recycle on EOF? True, then there is no way to control the params for each thread. For example, if 1 thread takes a long time to return.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find sort of a hack. Basically I just put a constant timer for each thread and used the thread number ${__threadNum} as the parameter to fit my constraint of having the same parameter to be used by the same thread.

I would still prefer a way to read the params from a csv file.